# Transfer outlook calendar to another user

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I created an extra outlook calendar under "My Calendars" for my team to share some due dates.  I've moved on to another department, and I want to transfer that calendar to another user.  I don't what to export/import - I would like to just transfer ownership.  Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: You don't.  Export the events and have the new user create a new  calendar and import the exported events.

Comment: @Marc - consider accepting the answer (and possibly upvoting) if it was helpful.

Comment: @miroxlav - I understand fully how stack exchange sites work. The provided answer doesn't answer the question I'm asking.  I will edit to be more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding meetings: Transfer of meeting ownership (change of organizer) is definitely not supported in Outlook 2010. Source: [google-fu](https://www.google.com/search?q=change+ownership+outlook+item) (some [prominent answer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/bd0408b9-a49b-476b-abfa-b1e1f44ce66a/in-outlook-2010-can-you-change-the-meeting-organizer) for all, also [one from serverfault site](https://serverfault.com/questions/461714/exchange-how-to-change-ownership-on-recurring-public-folder-calendar-items)).

Regarding other calendar items, I was unable to find out because at the moment I don't have someone to try with. I found that every item has an organizer and that field is read-only. You CAN change the organizer by entering and leaving schedule assistant with no invitations done. Then a field labeled `From` will become editable. But the item gets marked as apoointment. I'm not sure if this is the way to go. Maybe you can try in your environment and see if this technique leads somewhere. But it looked to me like a hack.

It is possible that only delete/recreate techniques help here like the one from Debra.

Answer (score 1):

You could export the calendar to ICAL and then the other user could import it.

Or you could just give the other user rights to it, and stop displaying it, though you would still own it.

To export/import using ICAL (ICS format, which is also compatible with most other calendar apps):

Export an Outlook calendar to ICS format:

1.In Outlook, in Calendar, select a calendar to make it the active calendar in the view.

2.On the File menu, click Save As

3.Type a name for the iCal file in the File name text box. This name should be easy to recognize and meaningful for you and your recipients.

A summary of the calendar name, date range, and detail level appears next to More Options. If you are satisfied with the summary, proceed to step 8, otherwise continue with step 4.

4.Click More Options.

5.From the Date Range list, choose the amount of calendar data to include in the iCal file, or click Specify dates to enter a custom date range.

6.From the Detail list, choose the amount of detail to show the recipients. By default, the Availability only option is selected. None of the options include your items marked private unless you change the privacy option in Advanced.

7.Optionally, click Show to see Advanced options.
Include details of items marked private. This option requires Detail to be set to Limited Details or Full Details. The existence of private items will be included, but no further information will be shared.
Include attachments within calendar items.  This option requires Detail to be set to Full Details. All attachments in calendar items, such as spreadsheets, are included. 
 Note   This might increase the size of the iCalendar file significantly.

8.Click OK, and then click Save.
If your calendar contains no items, a dialog box appears to provide you with a chance to cancel saving the iCalendar file.

Import ICAL -- other user:

1. Outlook 2010 and 2007: In Outlook 2010 Click on the File Tab -> Open -> Import
   In Outlook 2007 Click on the File Menu then click on Import and Export
2. Highlight “Import an iCalendar (.ics) or vCalendar file (.vcs)” then click Next
3. Choose the location where the iCalendar (.ics) file is saved and Click on Ok.
   Once the file is chosen the data will import to Open as New or Import
4. When the Open as New is chosen the file will open as a separate Calendar beside the Personal Exchange Calendar. Click the Import to actually import the data to the calendar.

The new calendar will typically carry the name of the ICS file, but can be renamed.

Answer (score 0):

to transfer the calendar, select email calendar to include whole calendar, full details, hit advanced - show and select both check boxes as desired and hit OK.

Once outlook finishes, you can either send the email to the person so they can import it or save the file and share the file (if it is a large file).
Have the new user import it to a new calendar and share that with the office.

Comment: This just summarises the existing answers.